# Usar ou não usar "Backing Bean"/"Manage Bean" com JSF?

Tags: java-ee, jsf-2.2

Na página 64 do e-book da Algaworks "Java EE 7, com JSF, PrimeFaces e CDI", explica a utilização dos backing beans, que são ***managers beans***, responsáveis por controlar os componentes das páginas JSF.

Porém no fim da explicação há um parágrafo que diz:

> "Apesar de poderoso, este recurso deve ser usado com bastante cuidado. O uso
>   excessivo pode deixar o código-fonte grande e difícil de entender. Na maioria das vezes, conseguimos fazer o que precisamos usando apenas expressões de ligação de valor. "

Então minha dúvida é a seguinte, por padrão devo ou não utilizar os ***backing beans***? Digo irei construir a aplicação e quero definir um padrão, então o certo é toda página ter um ***backing bean***, ou apenas as mais "complexas" o restante devo tratar em um ***manage-bean*** comum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende muito da sua aplicação, recomendo usar um `@ManagedBean` e definir um ciclo de vida para seu bean(`@ViewScoped`, `@RequestEscoped` ou `@SessionScoped`), com isso você já consegue desenvolver um aplicação tranquilo.

Answer (score 0):

**Diego Santos**,

O `ManagedBean` seria o seu `Controller` da aplicação, nossa `View` .xhtml no caso obtém o acesso as nossas propriedades seja no `ManagedBean` ou em nosso `BB` como no exemplo abaixo:

Declaração do `ManagedBean` ( A partir da versão 2.0 podemos fazer via `Annotations` antes disso apenas via `.xml`.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "comentario")
@ViewScoped <= Definição do escopo do ciclo de vida do seu ManagedBean
public class CComentario 
{
 private List<Anexo> listaAnexos; //Uma lista de Anexos

}
```

Na sua `View` podemos realizar validações tais como :

- Renderizar componentes
- Bloquear acesso
- Entre outros.

Para realizar uma validação utilizando a lista disponível no ManagedBean podemos fazer fazer da seguinte forma:

```
    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{fn:length(comentario.anexos) gt 0}">
       //aqui os elementos que serão renderizados
    </p:outputPanel>
```

Podemos também acessar atributos definidos no seu `Backing bean`

```
<strong> Comentário #{CComentario.comentario.descricao} </strong>
```

Vale muito a pena estudar o ciclo de vida de cada escopo que temos disponível como:

`@ApplicationScoped:` Ficará disponível o tempo todo até a aplicação "cair"

`@SessionScoped:` Fica disponível enquanto a sessão for valida.

`@ViewScoped:` Fica disponível apenas na pagina onde foi declarado.

`@RequestScoped:` Fica disponível entre uma única chamada http.

Temos também :

`@CustomScoped:` Onde você pode criar um escopo personalizado.

`@FlowScoped:` Você define o fluxo de vida por exemplo :Entra na vitrine > escolhe produto > compra produto > Fim . Este disponível **somente no jsf 2.2** pra cima